# Is there a WP Bakery-compatible WordPress plugin that works on multiple blocks?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wpbakery

I need a WordPress plugin that will let me hide a bunch of content until a user clicks on a Read More link.
Sounds easy, but here's the twist:

- I need to hide both text and images
- The content is set up in separate WP Bakery blocks
- All the plugins I found so far only work within a single block, they can't hide multiple blocks.

I'm a designer, not a developer, so I'm sure I'm missing something. Is there a reason this can't exist?
Please halp! I *really* don't want to redo the content.

[I talk in pictures better than in words, so here's an illustration of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAt40.jpg)